# Generate a calendar invite for the organizer

Tags: java, calendar, outlook, icalendar

I have a requirement where I want to send calendar invite to the organizer of the meeting. I was able to send the calendar invite successfully. This is the iCalendar file that i use to generate calendar invites:

> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>
> VERSION:2.0
>
> PRODID:-//Michael Angstadt//biweekly 0.4.1//EN
>
> METHOD:PUBLISH
>
> BEGIN:VEVENT
>
> UID:10b1d965-bdbd-425e-924f-14dba5d3b76d
>
> DTSTAMP:20150608T073620Z
>
> SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Summary of the event
>
> DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20150616T043000
>
> DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20150616T053000
>
> LOCATION:(231) 941-0107
>
> STATUS:CONFIRMED
>
> TRANSP:OPAQUE
>
> ORGANIZER;CN="Goel, Rahul":mailto:Rahul.Goel@gmail.com
>
> ATTENDEE;CN="Goel, Rahul":mailto:Rahul.Goel@gmail.com
>
> SEQUENCE:0
>
> BEGIN:VALARM
>
> ACTION:DISPLAY
>
> TRIGGER;RELATED=END:-PT15M
>
> DESCRIPTION:Reminder
>
> REPEAT:1
>
> END:VALARM
>
> END:VEVENT
>
> BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
>
> TZID:America/Los_Angeles
>
> TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/America/Los_Angeles
>
> X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Los_Angeles
>
> BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
>
> TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
>
> TZOFFSETTO:-0700
>
> TZNAME:PDT
>
> DTSTART:19700308T020000
>
> RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
>
> END:DAYLIGHT
>
> BEGIN:STANDARD
>
> TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
>
> TZOFFSETTO:-0800
>
> TZNAME:PST
>
> DTSTART:19701101T020000
>
> RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
>
> END:STANDARD
>
> END:VTIMEZONE
>
> END:VCALENDAR

But the problem comes when the organizer cancels the meeting. When the organizer cancels the meeting, I can see that the meeting is removed from the organizers calendar but still a notification alarm pops up 15 mins (as mentioned in the iCalendar file) before the scheduled meeting time. I don't want the notification alarm to pop-up if the meeting has been cancelled. Can you please help me resolve this ? Any help is welcome.

I am using biweekly API to generate the iCalendar file.

Comment: Did you try to compare iCalendar files generated by Outlook and biweekly? Is there any difference?

Comment: Eugene : I can check the icalendar file that is send out to attendees. But how can I see the icalendar file that Outlook generates for the organizer of the meeting? or are they both same?

Comment: How do you manage to Save the event in the calendar of the Organize of the event?
And did you resolve your problem?